# How to determine a wifi channel number used by wifi ap/network?

Tags: android, c, wifi

Ive discovered that several android wifi-apps (WiFi Manager, WiFi Analyzer) shows a channel number of WiFi network additionally to BSSID/SSID etc. But I can't find any info on how they do it. The only thing I know is I can get some wifi frequency. Maybe they determine a channel corresponding to that frequency? Is there a way to detect channel of wifi network in android at all? Of course this info is not a big deal and I can live without it :) but still i'm curious...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [Radio-Electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/wi-fi/80211-channels-number-frequencies-bandwidth.php), channel number is truly related with frequency.

```
CHA LOWER   CENTER  UPPER
NUM FREQ    FREQ    FREQ
    MHZ     MHZ     MHZ
  1 2401    2412    2423
  2 2406    2417    2428
  3 2411    2422    2433
  4 2416    2427    2438
  5 2421    2432    2443
  6 2426    2437    2448
  7 2431    2442    2453
  8 2436    2447    2458
  9 2441    2452    2463
 10 2446    2457    2468
 11 2451    2462    2473
 12 2456    2467    2478
 13 2461    2472    2483
 14 2473    2484    2495
```

For Android, [ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#frequency) contains the frequency of the channel.

Comment: Ive discovered that my android phone returns only center frequencies from ScanResult. So only those center frequencies are usable. Moreover some of lower and upper frequencies are the same for different channels - take a look at LF of 10th and 11th or UF of 11th and LF of 14th channels.

Comment: The IEE specification describing this is here (Page 566): http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2007.pdf In summary, the center frequency starts at 2412 MHz for channel 1 and increases by 5 MHz for every channel up to 13, with channel 14 designated specifically for Japan

Comment: what if device is connected to 5.4 Ghz or 4.9 Ghz frequency band?

Answer (score 17):

```
@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
private final static ArrayList<Integer> channelsFrequency = new ArrayList<Integer>(
        Arrays.asList(0, 2412, 2417, 2422, 2427, 2432, 2437, 2442, 2447,
                2452, 2457, 2462, 2467, 2472, 2484));

public static Integer getFrequencyFromChannel(int channel) {
    return channelsFrequency.get(channel);
}

public static int getChannelFromFrequency(int frequency) {
    return channelsFrequency.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(frequency));
}
```

Comment: Lemos,
Maybe you could help me out.....
I'm having similar wifi case unresolved...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357892/how-to-solve-discovering-other-device-via-wi-fi-android-api?noredirect=1#comment37663295_24357892

Answer (score 17):

You can express the conversion using a couple of formulas, one for each band. The function returns the channel of the given frequency or -1 in case that the frequency is not a valid wifi frequency (2.4GHz and 5GHz).

```
public static int convertFrequencyToChannel(int freq) {
    if (freq >= 2412 && freq <= 2484) {
        return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
    } else if (freq >= 5170 && freq <= 5825) {
        return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It is a compact way to do the same.

Comment: For frequency `2484` the returned channel is `15` while it should be `14`.

Answer (score 17):

According to standard [802.11-2012], there is a simpler way to work out channel number from frequency. Specifically,

`channel_center_frequency = channel_starting_frequency + 5 * channel_number`

For 5G band,
`channel_number` = 0, 1, ..., 200; `channel_starting_frequency` = 5000 MHz.

For 2.4G band,
`channel_number` = 1, 2, ..., 13; `channel_starting_frequency` = 2047 MHz.

The list of all channel frequencies can be found at [WiFi channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)

---

Translating this into code - refer to `iw` source:

```
int ieee80211_frequency_to_channel(int freq)
{
    if (freq == 2484)
        return 14;

    if (freq < 2484)
        return (freq - 2407) / 5;

    return freq/5 - 1000;
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution

Comment: It's very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the [answer by @artm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276767/816416), here is a more updated algorithm found in the Linux source code:

```
int ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel(u32 freq)
{
    /* TODO: just handle MHz for now */
    freq = KHZ_TO_MHZ(freq);

    /* see 802.11 17.3.8.3.2 and Annex J */
    if (freq == 2484)
        return 14;
    else if (freq < 2484)
        return (freq - 2407) / 5;
    else if (freq >= 4910 && freq <= 4980)
        return (freq - 4000) / 5;
    else if (freq < 5925)
        return (freq - 5000) / 5;
    else if (freq == 5935)
        return 2;
    else if (freq <= 45000) /* DMG band lower limit */
        /* see 802.11ax D6.1 27.3.22.2 */
        return (freq - 5950) / 5;
    else if (freq >= 58320 && freq <= 70200)
        return (freq - 56160) / 2160;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/wireless/util.c#L141, function name: `ieee80211_freq_khz_to_channel`