# how to solve discovering other device via Wi-Fi (android API)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wifi, broadcast

recently I follow the steps given from [Developer.Android.Com](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect)

But it seems i have a few luck over there.
I tried to discover the available peers nearby,
put 'em into the arraylist but seems no luck. I didnt get anything.

My Actual 2 Devices are actually android 4.1 and 4.2
Since Wifi Direct is based on API Level 14 which is android 4.0+ so
i think my real device is not the problem.

The concept I use is 
using 1 activity and 1 BroadCast Receiver.

Please take a look at my code, did I put it wrongly or something I forgot?

**Chat1Activity.java**

```
package com.example.androtut;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import others.MyBroadcastReceiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chat1Activity extends Activity {

    private final IntentFilter mintentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel mChannel;
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private ArrayList peers = new ArrayList();
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener = new PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {

            // Out with the old, in with the new.
            peers.clear();
            peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

            // If an AdapterView is backed by this data, notify it
            // of the change.  For instance, if you have a ListView of available
            // peers, trigger an update.

            if (peers.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"We've found " + peers.size() + " users", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat1);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi is okay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        prepareIntentFilter();

        Button btn_startchat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_startchat);

        // Listening to News Feed button click
        btn_startchat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen
                detectPeers();
            }
        });

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    }


    private void detectPeers(){

        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // Code for when the discovery initiation is successful goes here.
                // No services have actually been discovered yet, so this method
                // can often be left blank.  Code for peer discovery goes in the
                // onReceive method, detailed below.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                // Code for when the discovery initiation fails goes here.
                // Alert the user that something went wrong.
            }
    });




    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this, myPeerListListener);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mintentFilter);
    }
    /* unregister the broadcast receiver */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    private void prepareIntentFilter() {

        mintentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        // Indicates a change in the list of available peers.
        mintentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        // Indicates the state of Wi-Fi P2P connectivity has changed.
        mintentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        // Indicates this device's details have changed.
        mintentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    }


}
```

And the **MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package others;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.androtut.Chat1Activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private Channel mChannel;
    private Chat1Activity mActivity;
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener;



    public MyBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            Chat1Activity activity, PeerListListener obPeerList) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.myPeerListListener = obPeerList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers

            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, myPeerListListener);
            }



        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION
                .equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION
                .equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing



        }

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi P2P is enabled
                Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),"Wifi is okay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // Wi-Fi P2P is not enabled
                Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Wifi is not okay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In your android folder, they have given a wifi direct demo, you can navigate to this folder ..samples/android-14/WiFiDirectDemo

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Hardik4560, but could you check out my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you did't add PeerListListener to your activity. so it won't reply.

you can try to implement PeerListListener in your activity

```
public class Chat1Activity extends Activity implements WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener
```

and override onPeerAvailable method in your activity

```
 @Override
  public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {

   //put your code here

  }
```

and change requestPeers method in your Receiver

```
 if (mManager != null) {
            mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, mActivity);
 }
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: great! Altough i found my own answer instead of this, but thanks! :D

Answer (score -1):

Have you check whether your device support Wifi Direct?
Having a rom > 4.0 does not means it has wifi direct hardware support.
Try to check that with PackageManager's API:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: please check out the question code before you give an answer @jobcrazy,.....

bcoz from MyBroadcastReceiver.java
You can see the state whether its wifi direct functional or not is tested there.

Somethingelse must be forgotten other than that.

Comment: You mean that you have got Wi-fi P2P state changed broadcasts but without any device nearby or you haven't receive any broadcast at all?

Comment: the other devices are not showing inside the list. Check the code please...... is there something I forgot?